# Reescrever URL para acessos à "root" mas não bloquear acesso aos sub-domínios

Tags: apache, htaccess, subdomínio, mod-rewrite

Tenho o seguinte código que faz a rescrita do URL introduzido para identificar correctamente as áreas, sub-áreas e ID de conteúdo a que o visitante está a tentar aceder:

```htaccess
# Rewrite the url
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine On

  # Redirect when we have a single parameter
  RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?mod=$1
  RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?mod=$1

  # Redirect when we have two parameters
  RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?mod=$1&call=$2
  RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?mod=$1&call=$2

  # Redirect when we have three parameters
  RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)$ index.php?mod=$1&call=$2&id=$3
  RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)/$ index.php?mod=$1&call=$2&id=$3

</IfModule>
```

## Problema

No domínio existem sub-domínios que deixam de ficar acessíveis se o `.htaccess` na raiz contém o código em cima apresentado.

**Estrutura**

```
public_html        // root         http://www.meuSite.com/
public_html/cdn    // sub-domínio  http://cdn.meuSite.com/
public_html/app    // sub-domínio  http://app.meuSite.com/
```

## Pergunta

Como utilizar reescrita de URL para a pasta principal, mas continuar a permitir acesso directo às pastas na raiz (*sub-domínios*) ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### RewriteCond

Voce deve usar a diretiva [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) para adicionar condições para aplicar ou não o redirecionamento.

Por exemplo:

```htaccess
# Redirect when we have a single parameter
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?mod=$1
```

Neste caso, as flags `!-f` e `!-d` estão determinando que o redirect só ocorrera **se não existir arquivo ou pasta com a url correspondente**.

### Sintaxe

A sintaxe do comando é:

```htaccess
RewriteCond TestString CondPattern
```

Onde `CondPattern` é uma *REGEXP* compatível com perl, com alguns acréscimos.

Voce pode prefixar o pattern com `!` para inverter seu efeito. Há algumas variações que permitem usar o `CondPattern` sem *REGEXP* também:

```htaccess
'<CondPattern'
'>CondPattern'
'=CondPattern'
```

Essas últimas três tratam a `CondPattern` literalmente como string, e comparam respectivamente a `TestString` com o valor literal da `CondPattern`

**Veja mais algumas condições:**

- `-d` Pega o o resultado da `TestString` e verifica se é um diretório existente
- `-f` Pega o o resultado da `TestString` e verifica se é um arquivo existente
- `-s` Faz o mesmo que o `-f`, mas só considera arquivos não-vazios
- `-l` Verifica se o resultado da `TestString` é caminho para um link simbólico
- `-x` Verifica se o resultado da `TestString` é um caminho com permissão +x
- `-F` Equivale ao `-f`, mas faz um teste pra ver se o arquivo é realmente acessível pelo Apache. Isso implica em fazer uma requisição interna extra no teste, cuidado com uso em excesso.
- `-U` Mesmo que o `-F`, mas testa por URL e não Path

Todos estes testes podem ser negados com uma `!` no início.

### Aplicando ao caso prático

**Uma possível solução para tratar a questão da pergunta:**

```htaccess
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^cdn\.meusite\.com\.br$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_-]*)(/([a-z0-9_-]*))?(/([0-9]*))?(/)?$
   cdn/index.php?mod=$1&call=$3&id=$5 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^app\.meusite\.com\.br$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_-]*)(/([a-z0-9_-]*))?(/([0-9]*))?(/)?$
   app/index.php?mod=$1&call=$3&id=$5 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_-]*)(/([a-z0-9_-]*))?(/([0-9]*))?(/)?$
   index.php?mod=$1&call=$3&id=$5 [NC,L]
```

> Não quebre as linhas no RewriteRule! Quebrei no exemplo apenas para legibilidade.

Notar que este último caso é mais complexo e utilizamos algumas coisas mais avançadas:

- Utilizamos a *flag* NC (nocase) para tratar maiúsculas e minúsculas igualmente
- Utilizamos a *flag* L (last) para não processar o resto do rewrite caso alguma das condições seja satisfeita
- Em vez de três linhas diferentes para atender um, dois ou três parâmetros, resolvemos com uma só, transformando os parâmetros dois e três e a barra final em opcionais usando `( )?` nos *regex*. Isso implicou em mudar os números dos grupos para `$1`, `$3` e `$5` na string de saída.
- Leia na documentação sobre as *flags* NE e QSA se estiver com problemas com *query strings* não se comportando bem, ou se além dos parâmetros mod, call e id precisar de outros fornecidos diretamente pelas páginas.

**Aplicando as exceções de arquivo e diretório no exemplo inicial:**

```htaccess
  # Redirect when we have a single parameter
  RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f 
  RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?mod=$1

  RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f 
  RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?mod=$1

  # Redirect when we have two parameters
  RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f 
  RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?mod=$1&call=$2

  RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f 
  RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?mod=$1&call=$2

  # Redirect when we have three parameters
  RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f 
  RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)$ index.php?mod=$1&call=$2&id=$3

  RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f 
  RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)/$ index.php?mod=$1&call=$2&id=$3
```

Notem que neste caso tivemos que repetir o `RewriteCond`, pois ele vale apenas para o primeiro `RewriteRule` que encontrar pela frente.

> A idéia desta resposta foi mostrar uma solução pertinente à pergunta. O `mod_rewrite` é um tanto complexo para tratarmos de todos os detalhes, então o ideal é realmente **ler a [documentação](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html)**.