# Liberar acesso a página 404.html com .htaccess

Tags: htaccess

estou com um problema ao tentar liberar acesso a página 404.html através do meu .htaccess, sempre dá Internal Server Error. Como devo aplicar uma regra para apenas o 404.html seja liberada para acesso direto?

.htaccess:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ index.php?page=$1&sub=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ index.php?page=$1&sub=$2&id=$3 [L]

<Files *.php>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Files>

<Files index.php>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Files>
```

Comment: Raiz, Na mesma pasta de index :D

Comment: Meu .htaccess bloqueia o acesso direto a arquivos .html e .php, apenas .jpg, .css, .js estão liberados. Gostaria de liberar acesso também aos arquivos .html no geral.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você pode tentar da seguinte forma:

```htaccess
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ index.php?page=$1&sub=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ index.php?page=$1&sub=$2&id=$3 [L]

<Files *.php>
   Order Deny,Allow
   Deny from all
   Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Files>

<Files index.php>
   Order Allow,Deny
   Allow from all
</Files>
```

eliminando o `RewriteRule ^.*$` inicial, para só redirecionar caso não exista o arquivo correspondente (lembrando que cada conjunto de `RewriteCond`s só vale para o `RewriteRule` seguinte).

Veja mais nesta resposta:

[Reescrever URL para acessos à "root" mas não bloquear acesso aos sub-domínios](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2415/reescrever-url-para-acessos-a-root-mas-nao-bloquear-acesso-aos-sub-dominios/2416#2416)

Comment: Deu certo, porém os arquivos .php ficaram acessíveis, e quero bloquear.

Comment: Está resolvido, obrigado. irei dá uma olhada na resposta.

Comment: Tentei por o caso do .php, mas não testei. Veja se funciona, é importante deixarmos a pergunta e a resposta em ordem, pois isto pode ajudar outros usuários.

Comment: Não funciona desta maneira, Quando utilizado o <Files> está bloqueando normalmente os arquivos .php para acesso diferente de 127.0.0.1.

Comment: deixei com o files então.