# Caso específico de RewriteRule para uma URL

Tags: php, htaccess

Tenho um `.htaccess` reescrevendo as URLs e um submenu sendo criado dinâmicamente e preciso que um destes links seja aberto em outra URL/página diferente do restante.

Está assim:

```
RewriteRule conheca/(.+)/(.+)/$ conheca.php?id=$1&slug=$2
```

Preciso que o caso específico `conheca/2/equipe-pastoral/` seja direcionado para `equipe-pastoral.php` e não para o `conheca.php`, como é o caso das URLs restantes.

Utilizando

```
RedirectMatch 301 conheca/2/equipe-pastoral/$ page_diferente.php
```

ela conseguiu se distinguir das demais porém acontece o erro 500 mesmo a `page_diferente.php` existindo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basta colocar a regra específica para esta página antes da regra geral, e usar a flag [L] na regra específica para indicar que após a mesma, as seguintes devem ser ignoradas.

Veja mais sobre `rewriterule` e `rewritecond` nesta questão:

[Reescrever URL para acessos à "root" mas não bloquear acesso aos sub-domínios](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2415/reescrever-url-para-acessos-a-root-mas-nao-bloquear-acesso-aos-sub-dominios)

Comment: Consegui resolver com a ajuda deste post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11691916/removing-php-file-extension-from-the-end-of-a-url 

Creio que estava errando ao fazer a reescrita para retirar .php dos links. Obrigado!