# Como resolver problemas na chamada de arquivos no HTML?

Tags: php, html, url

Estou com uma estrutura de pastas onde tenho a seguinte arquitetura

```
page
    php
        arquivos.php
    tpl
        arquivos.tpl(html)
    style
        arquivos.css
```

Mas tenho um problema em chamar os arquivos nas tpl's...
quando uso o caminho

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../style/style.css" />
```

Ele volta para fora da raiz do projeto 
estou tentando usar URL's amigaveis o .htaccess está assim

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    Options -Indexes
    ErrorDocument 404 /Errors/404.html
    ErrorDocument 403 /Errors/403.html
    RewriteRule ^/?$ page/php/Home.php [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^contato/?$ page/php/Contato.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi esse problema criando uma variável que guarda o Diretório do projeto, faço isso comparando o caminho do servidor com o da url e e gravando as pastas semelhantes, após isso apenas coloco a variável como prefixo de todas as URL's do site.

```
$UrlSite = explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,trim(parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],PHP_URL_PATH), '/\\'));
$DirSite = explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,__DIR__);
if(in_array($UrlSite[0], $DirSite) AND $UrlSite[0] != ''){
    $Directory = "/$UrlSite[0]/";
    $smarty->assign('Directory',$Directory);
}else{
    $Directory = "/";
    $smarty->assign('Directory',$Directory);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Um dos passos é acrescentar estas `RewriteCond` para fazer o *rewrite* apenas quando não existir arquivo ou pasta com o nome solicitado:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?$ page/php/Home.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^contato/?$ page/php/contato.php [NC,L]
```

Adicionalmente, nos casos em que o CSS for geral, usar caminhos relativos à raiz:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/style/style.css" />
```

Para CSS relativo ao documento corrente, só olhando o caso específico mesmo. Lembre-se que o que vale é o caminho final de onde está sendo servida a página, e não onde o script/template se encontra de fato. Quem vai resolver este caminho é o browser, e não o apache, então leve em consideração o caminho que aparece ao navegar nas páginas.

Veja um pouco mais sobre rewrite **[nesta questão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2415/reescrever-url-para-acessos-a-root-mas-nao-bloquear-acesso-aos-sub-dominios/)**.